# Intuit SDK paymernt merge

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We're currently using the Intuit SDK version 10 to sync to our app, we use /n software QuickBooks Integrator, and are querying QB for payments by QB Date Modified. We're experiencing random results from QB on returning payments, entered after our date trigger, the last modified date of the QB payment. We are wondering of there are actions in QB that can cause the payment modified date to be set to something other then the current date of the transaction which would cause them to be overlooked by the query. 
Using QB 2012 Ent in this example,SDK 10,QBFC_10

Thanks,
Mark